# Continually subtracting from a running total

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Using Amazon Redshift, I have a table with the columns: streamers, start_time, end_time and total_streamers. Start_time and end_time are in seconds from midnight, streamers refers to music streamers, and total_streamers is a running total of streamers. I want to figure out how many streamers there are at any given start_time. Here is the table I am getting.

```
streamers   start_time  end_time    total_streamers
  2            240         400         2 
  10           300         460         12
  7            360         514         19
  12           420         608         31
```

The problem I'm running into is that once the start_time exceeds one of the previous end_times, I no longer want the streamers included in my total_streamers. Since the first rows end_time is 400, the 2 streamers for that row should be excluded once start_time is greater than 400. 
Here is my desired result.

```
streamers   start_time  end_time    total_streamers
  2            240         400         2 
  10           300         460         12
  7            360         514         19
  12           420         608         29
```

Let me know if I can provide any code or clarifying questions for what I am asking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your results don't make sense.  At time 240 there are 2; at 300, 12; at 360 19; at 400, 17; at 460, 7; and so on.  How are your numbers calculated?

Comment: Yes, so what you have written out is the desired result. I have it being calculated using a running total, but that running total does not take into account my end_times. This is what I am unsure how to do. The streamers is streams that were started in that minute.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s.n, SUM(tx.streamers) sm
  FROM generate_series(1,1000) s(n)
  LEFT JOIN tx ON s.n BETWEEN tx.start_time and tx.end_time
  GROUP BY s.n
)
SELECT DISTINCT tx.*, cte.sm AS total_streamers
FROM tx
JOIN cte
  ON cte.n =tx.start_time
ORDER BY start_time;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f6e56faa89fe413f3f6b86073e508028)**

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ streamers ║ start_time ║ end_time ║ total ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 2         ║ 240        ║ 400      ║ 2     ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 10        ║ 300        ║ 460      ║ 12    ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 7         ║ 360        ║ 514      ║ 19    ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12        ║ 420        ║ 608      ║ 29    ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

If needed you could get value for every second:

```
SELECT s.n, SUM(tx.streamers) sm
FROM generate_series(1,1000) s(n)
LEFT JOIN tx ON s.n BETWEEN tx.start_time and tx.end_time
GROUP BY s.n
ORDER BY n;
```

**EDIT**

Without `generate_series`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s.n, SUM(tx.streamers) sm
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) AS n
        FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) y(n),
             (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) x(n),
             (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) z(n)) s
  LEFT JOIN tx ON s.n BETWEEN tx.start_time and tx.end_time
  GROUP BY s.n
)
SELECT DISTINCT tx.*, cte.sm
FROM tx
JOIN cte
  ON cte.n =tx.start_time
ORDER BY start_time;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9554673e1450d87c791eab40fb828a2d)**

Comment: i don't think Redshift supports [`generate_series`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala You could exchange it with any method to generate tally table.

Comment: sure i agree..just mentioned it so other users will not find it misleading.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
    ,(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(streamers),0) FROM Table t2 WHERE t2.end_time > t1.start_time AND t2.start_time <= t1.start_time) as total_streamers
FROM
    Table t1
```

While there are probably ways of doing this using window functions it is probably just easier as a derived column with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Final query

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT
      t1.start_time,
      t1.end_time,
      t2.streamers
    FROM t t1
      LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.start_time BETWEEN t2.start_time AND t2.end_time
) SELECT
    start_time,
    end_time,
    SUM(streamers)
  FROM q
  GROUP BY start_time, end_time
  ORDER BY start_time;
```

To better understand this query, take a look at slightly modified version 
of subquery q below.

```
SELECT
  t1.start_time AS original_start_time,
  t2.start_time AS matching_start_time,
  t2.end_time AS matching_end_time,
  t2.streamers AS matching_streamers
FROM t t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.start_time BETWEEN t2.start_time AND t2.end_time
ORDER BY t1.start_time,t2.start_time;
```

And now, subquery results.

```
original_start_time matching_start_time matching_end_time   matching_streamers

240 240 400 2

300 240 400 2
300 300 460 10

360 240 400 2
360 300 460 10
360 360 514 7

420 300 460 10
420 360 514 7
420 420 608 12
```

What's in the result above? For every new "stream" (e.g. 300,460) the subquery is locating all "streams" (including itself) in which that new "stream" start time is between their start and end time. For example, at 300, we have had a new stream (300,460) and still running (240,400), and so on.

Given the above results, all we have to do is sum streamers of all matching streams for each stream.

**EDIT**

Note that Redshfit doesn't support "VALUES list used as constant tables" which has been used in lad2025's answer. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html